# The use of FacebookAuthProvider in apps

Tags: api, servicestack

I've been working with ServiceStack for quite some time now and i love it. But there is one thing i can't figure out.
How are app's (ios, android etc.) that are using my servicestack endpoints, suppose to use the facebook endpoint "/auth/facebook"?
When using this url "/auth/facebook" from the browser it works fine, but the response is html, and not an AuthResponse og something serializable.

Is this endpoint only to be used from websites with servicestack in the same solution?

Answer (score 2):

The way that stuff works is by redirecting the user to Facebook with an API key that matches your app. The user then tells Facebook that your app is ok, and Facebook redirects them back. This can only be done via a browser. You really have two options to work around this:

- Make the user authenticate with Facebook using a website and then authenticate your user with credentials from the app.
- Use the built in iOS Facebook stuff and send the resulting auth tokens to an endpoint on your app, where you can save them for later use.

Edit, a bit more clarification:

**Option 1**

1. User Goes to your website
2. User Clicks on your Auth With Facebook button
3. User is sent your your Facebook endpoint set up in Service Stack
4. User is redirected by Service Stack to Facebook
5. User is redirected back to Service Stack from Facebook, with a token in the url
6. You save the token in your database and tell the user they can now user your app with Facebook.

**Option 1.5**

The same as **Option 1** but instead of making the user go through their browser you create a `UIWebView` control and point it to your Facebook Auth endpoint. Then you listen for a response from your site that says the user is authenticated.  I'm not a objective c, so I can't really get more detailed on how to do that.

**Option 2**

1. Use the iOS Facebook API and handle authentication [as seen here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/).
2. `POST` the credentials to Service Stack via a Custom Endpoint
3. Save credentials in the db, and use them in the future to make calls on behalf of the user.

Facebook Login requires a browser of some sort, because Facebook's cookies must be passed along with a request to authorize your website.  That is how Facebook knows which of it's users wants to authorize your site, and that *they* are the ones making the request.

Comment: @option 1: how will the app know the trip to Facebook was successfull, when we are not in the app anymore? And when successfull, what are the credentials to be used against auth/credentials? The same as Facebook?

Comment: @option 2: what is the built in ios Facebook Stuff? I've been searching for almost everything related to servicestack, and haven't stumbled upon that. Will this be able to send an auth response to the app? I guess this cant be used for android?

Comment: I elaborated a bit, also I meant the Facebook iOS SDK.